# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed

Tags: javascript, html, css, progressive-web-apps, typeerror

I am creating a Progressive Web App for a university project, but when I checked the console I have this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed - serviceworker.js:1

I don't understand where this error is coming from.

The HTML and CSS are showing on as expected, but when I do a PWA audit from the Chrome Dev Tools, it's showing [these failures. They are 'no service worker', 'no 200 when offline' and 'user not prompted to install web app'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjthH.png)

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  color: #4E5863;
}

.indexLogo{
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E9F2;
}

.intuPotteriesLogo, .manchesterAirportLogo{
  width: 252px;
  height: auto;
}

.indexTitle{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E9F2;
  font-size: 24px;
}

header{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#headerStokeCityOfCulture{
  width: 100%;
}

#container{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hotLinks{
  border: 2px solid #ABB5C3;
  width: 22%;
  margin: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hotLinksLogos{
  width: 100%;
}

.hotLinksTitle{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ABB5C3;
}

.searchBarContainer{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E9F2;
}

.searchBox{
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E5E9F2;
  border: none;
  color: black;
}

.bookingItem{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E9F2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.bookingItemIcon{
  height: 60px;
}

.bookingItemLeft{
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.bookingItemRight{
  width: 65%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.bookingTitle{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.bookingAddress{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

#searchPageContainer{
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: #F7F8F8;
  text-align: center;
}

.searchIdeas{
  padding: 10px;
  color: #515B64;
}

.searchIdeasFirstItem{
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.profileContainer{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E9F2;
}

.profilePictureContainer{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#profilePicture{
  height: 100px;
}

#userName{
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.profileDetailsContainer{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 55%;
}

#fullUserName{
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#usersHometown{
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.tripsFriendsPhotosContainer{
  width: 40%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.recentTripLogos{
  border: 2px solid #ABB5C3;
  width: 42%;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

fieldset{
  margin: 20px;
  border: none;
}

input[type=text]{
    width: 80%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=radio]{
  margin: 10px 0;
}

label{
  padding-right: 10px;
}

textarea{
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.formTitles{
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#reviewInstructions{
  margin: 20px;
}

#submitButton{
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #48525E;
  color: white;
}

footer{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #ABB5C3;
  background-color: white;
  clear: both;
}

.footerLinks{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.footerIcons{
  height: 30px;
}

.discoverContainer, .discoverDescription, .discoverDirections, .discoverTitle, .discoverDirectionsTitle, .discoverReviewHeading,
.discoverReview, .discoverReviewTitle, .discoverContentPhotos, .bookingQrCodesContainer, .profileContainer, .container{
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.discoverContainer, .bookingQrCodesContainer, .profileContainer{
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.discoverPhotos{
  width: 40%;
}

.recentTripsContainer a img{
  width: 25%;
}

h1{
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

h2{
  font-size: 16px;
}





@media screen
  and (max-width: 600px) {

  .profileContainer, .container{
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
  }

  body{
    margin-bottom: 70px;
  }

  .hotLinks{
    border: 2px solid #ABB5C3;
    width: 43%;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .footerLinks{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .footerIconsContainer{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 24%;
  }

  .footerIcons{
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0 0;
  }

  .footerIconText{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 5px;
  }

  footer{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid #ABB5C3;
    background-color: white;
    clear: both;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .discoverContainer{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .discoverLogo{
    padding: 20px 10px;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
  }

  .discoverAddress{
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }

  .discoverDescription, .discoverDirections, .discoverReview{
    clear: both;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .discoverDirectionsTitle, .discoverTitle, .memberSinceTitle, .reviewsTitle{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
  }

  .discoverReviewTitle{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  }

  #map{
    width: 90%;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: grey;
  }

  .discoverContentPhotos{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .discoverTitle{
    text-align: left;
  }

  .discoverPhotos{
    width: 46%;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .bookingQrCodesContainer{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .aboutUserTitle{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  .aboutUserText, .aboutUserTitle, .usersReview{
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }

  .reviewTitles{
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }

  #submitReviewsButton{
    margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #48525E;
    color: white;
  }

  .reviewForm{
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

  #todaysWeatherTitle{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  #container-openweathermap-widget-12 > div{
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
  }

  .weather-left-card__wind, .weather-left-card__link, .weather-left-card__links span, .weather-left-card__rising{
    font-size: 16px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta name="description" content="An application to learn about Stoke on Trent's events and places to visit!">
    <title>Voyage App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicons.ico/favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 class="indexTitle">Discover Stoke-on-Trent</h1>
    </header>
    <picture id="headerStokeCityOfCulture">
      <source class="full-width" media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="images/cityOfCulture-large.jpg">
      <source class="full-width" media="(min-width: 420px)" srcset="images/cityOfCulture-medium.jpg">
      <img src="images/cityOfCulture-small.jpg" alt="Stoke City of Culture" style="width:100%;">
    </picture>
    <div id="container">
      <a href="intupotteries.html">
        <div class="hotLinks">
          <img class="hotLinksLogos" src="images/intuPotteries.jpg" alt="intu Potteries Shopping Centre Logo">
          <h4 class="hotLinksTitle">intu Potteries</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="emmabridgewater.html">
        <div class="hotLinks">
          <img class="hotLinksLogos" src="images/emmaBridgewater.jpg" alt="Emma Bridgewater Pottery Logo">
          <h4 class="hotLinksTitle">Emma Bridgewater</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="altontowers.html">
        <div class="hotLinks">
          <img class="hotLinksLogos" src="images/altonTowers.jpg" alt="Alton Towers Theme Park Logo">
          <h4 class="hotLinksTitle">Alton Towers</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="trenthamEstate.html">
        <div class="hotLinks">
          <img class="hotLinksLogos" src="images/trenthamEstate.jpg" alt="Trentham Estate Logo">
          <h4 class="hotLinksTitle">Trentham Estate</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="bet365.html">
        <div class="hotLinks">
          <img class="hotLinksLogos" src="images/bet365.jpg" alt="Bet365 Stadium Logo - The home of Stoke City Football Club">
          <h4 class="hotLinksTitle">Bet365 Stadium</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="freeportTalke.html">
        <div class="hotLinks">
          <img class="hotLinksLogos" src="images/freeportTalke.jpg" alt="Freeport Talke Shopping Centre Logo">
          <h4 class="hotLinksTitle">Freeport Talke</h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <h4 id="todaysWeatherTitle">Todays Weather</h4>
      <div id="weatherContainer"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <a class="footerLinks" href="index.html">
        <div id="discover" class="footerIconsContainer">
          <img class="footerIcons" src="images/binoculars.jpg" alt="Binoculars icon">
          <p class="footerIconText">Discover</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="footerLinks" href="bookings.html">
        <div id="bookings" class="footerIconsContainer">
          <img class="footerIcons" src="images/ticket.jpg" alt="Binoculars icon">
          <p class="footerIconText">Bookings</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="footerLinks" href="search.html">
        <div id="search" class="footerIconsContainer">
          <img class="footerIcons" src="images/search.jpg" alt="Binoculars icon">
          <p class="footerIconText">Search</p>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="footerLinks" href="account.html">
        <div id="account" class="footerIconsContainer">
          <img class="footerIcons" src="images/person.jpg" alt="Binoculars icon">
          <p class="footerIconText">Account</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </footer>
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
          navigator.serviceWorker.register('serviceworker.js').then(function(registration) {
          console.log('Service worker registered successfully', registration);
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Service worker registration failed: ', err);
        });
      };
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.10.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="serviceworker.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var cache_name = 'gih-cache';
var cached_urls = [
  'offline.html',
  'fourohfour.html',
  'account.html',
  'altontowers.html',
  'bet365.html',
  'booking-altonTowers.html',
  'booking-manchesterAirport.html',
  'booking-northStaffsHotel.html',
  'bookings.html',
  'emmabridgewater.html',
  'freeportTalke.html',
  'index.html',
  'intupotteries.html',
  'search.html',
  'trenthamEstate.html',
  'style.css'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cache_name)
    .then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(cached_urls);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (cacheName.startsWith('pages-cache-') && staticCacheName !== cacheName) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    console.log('Fetch event for ', event.request.url);
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          console.log('Found ', event.request.url, ' in cache');
          return response;
        }
        console.log('Network request for ', event.request.url);
        return fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 404) {
            return caches.match('fourohfour.html');
          }
          return caches.open(cached_urls).then(function(cache) {
           cache.put(event.request.url, response.clone());
            return response;
          });
        });
      }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error, ', error);
        return caches.match('offline.html');
      })
    );
  });
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this code! Cleared up some understanding I still needed with service workers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
<script src="serviceworker.js"></script>
```

You're not supposed to include your SW as a script in the page. You're only supposed to interact with it by calling the `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` as you do in your script above.

Lighthouse is not reporting it but I'm making sure: you're serving the website overt HTTPS right?

Comment: The serviceworker.js is the code to access the cached files and to do the 'install, activate, fetch'. Are sure that this line of code should be removed, how would the service worker know where to look? - Yes it's being  served over https too.

Comment: Yes. Completely sure. Your call to navigator.serviceWorker.register() will *get* the file.

Comment: In my case i did not not included service worker still getting error ?

Comment: I find the inclusion of the script is required, and is recommended by other PWA developers such as: https://blog.heroku.com/how-to-make-progressive-web-app I hate giving downvotes. Sorry.

Comment: @DavidJ that is simply not true. How Service Workers work is that you put them in a single file, usually service-worker.js, and then call navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js') in your application code. That's how you register a Service Worker. Of course you can name your files anyway you like and implement whatever logic in them, but that's the only base principle here that you have to follow. If you want to give a downvote you're welcome to do so. Doesn't bother me at all.

Answer (score 41):

I had a typo in one of the filenames that I had added to cached_urls. It did not match the name of the real file so I kept getting the error

I found it by quickly setting cached_urls to an empty list and found that the error went away.

Comment: I created file in wrong directory, but almost the same as typo. I am writing this here so maybe someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error. The error log is very succint but as previously mentionned, it is very likely to originate from failed request from the service worker to request page from the server.

The trick is to understand the [service worker scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/register#Parameters). By default, its scope is the directory it's in. If you access your service worker script from `https://your.domain.com/static/service-worker.js`, its default scope will be `/static`. So, if you type `cache.add('index.html')`, it will actually request `https://your.domain.com/static/index.html`, which will result in an error if you were trying to get `https://your.domain.com/index.html`. Two solutions:

- Access files using relative paths: `cache.add('../index.html')`
- Change the scope when registering:

  - Use `navigator.serviceWorker.register('static/service-worker.js', {scope: '/'})`
  - Add the HTTP header `Service-Worker-Allowed: /` when serving your website

Comment: Right, and it can be checked. console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);

Comment: This is essential: "The trick is to understand the service worker scope."

Answer (score 10):

Add '/'. Your cached_urls members require you to include the slash sign:

```js
var cached_urls = [
  '/offline.html',
  '/fourohfour.html',
  '/account.html',
  '/altontowers.html',
  '/bet365.html',
  '/booking-altonTowers.html',
  '/booking-manchesterAirport.html',
  '/booking-northStaffsHotel.html',
  '/bookings.html',
  '/emmabridgewater.html',
  '/freeportTalke.html',
  '/index.html',
  '/intupotteries.html',
  '/search.html',
  '/trenthamEstate.html',
  '/style.css'
];
```

Comment: It was solved to me with this simple tip. Thank you. At 'const offlineFallbackPage' I put this slash and the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

i had exactly the same error, trying to figure out the PWA concept and cache API, with this code (extract)

```
    installEvent.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName)
    .then( staticCache =>{
        // fichiers souhaités en cache
        staticCache.addAll([
            '/assets/font.txt', 
            '/assets/icon.txt'
        ])
        // fichiers à mettre impérativement en cache
        return staticCache.addAll([
            'css/stylesheet.css',
            'js/javascript.js'
        ])
    })
)
```

the fact is that the files in the array were dummy names.
When i created for real the files and the folders (css/stylesheet.css), the service worker went on, and the error disappeared

Answer (score 1):

added "." before all of my paths in "filesToCache", like:
"/index.html" changes to "./index.html"
and it works. Way to go!