# Js Error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed in first line

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to add a Service Worker to my website. The problem is when is register my service worker I got an error from my service worker file `sw.js` : *Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed*
Here is the code from `sw.js`:

```
const cacheName = 'v1'; // The error append here

const cacheAssets = [
    'index.html'
];

// Call Install Event
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Installed');

    e.waitUntil(
        caches
            .open(cacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                console.log('Service Worker: Caching Files');
                cache.addAll(cacheAssets);
            })
            .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
    );
});

// Call Activate Event
self.addEventListener('activate', e => {
    console.log('Service Worker: Activated');
});
```

The error is in the first line and I don't understand why

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

Here is my register code that I called into my web page (It is called at the start just under the `<body>`):

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
        navigator.serviceWorker
            .register('../scripts/sw.js')
            .then(reg => console.log('Service Worker: Registered'))
            .catch(err => console.log(`Service Worker: Error: ${err}`));
    });
}else{
    console.log('no service worker');
}
```

Comment: did you add a catch block? it seems that your cache name is undefiend so the promise fails, try adding a catch block to your promise chain, `.catch(err => console.log(err))`

Comment: do not add sw.js file yourself, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844781/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-request-failed

Comment: but I'm not doing it

Comment: the try catch gives me the same error. Maybe it's the way I called the script that is wrong

Comment: MSIE, perchance?

Comment: what is actually MSIE ?

Comment: Microsoft Internet Explorer.

Comment: No I'm on Chrome

Comment: Then the only other thing I can think of is something wrong with the script path and/or the `index.html`'s `<base href>`.

Comment: All the paths look good. It's another issue I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I change
`const cacheName = 'v1';`
to
`const cacheName = 'MYWEBSITENAME';`
And it works but
If anyone can explain to me why it will be a pleasure*

**EDIT**

The error is due to the `index.html` who doesn't exist  my bad
Into the `cacheAssets`, you can not register folder